# PHP - Why is looping between WHILE and DO-WHILE give different results in mysql fetching?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one record in a table in my mysql database. I use the following PHP code to retrieve data:

```
$result = mysql_query($query = "SELECT realname FROM t_user");

if($result)
{
  while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $data['realname'];
  }
}
```

the results do not appear, but when I use a **do-while** loop like below:

```
if($result)
{
  $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  do{
    echo $data['realname'];
  } while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
}
```

the results appear, then I tried to add one more record to the table, in the **while** loop, only shows one data record (the first record), and the **do-while** loop displays all the data. Why is that? Is it because there is my code wrong?

Comment: The error's probably somewhere else.

Comment: @irrelephant: how to find the cause? No warning error is displayed in the browser?

Comment: @DrewPierce: but i don't want using PDO :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have shown can't possibly exhibit this problem, so the logical explanation is this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query = "SELECT realname FROM t_user");

if($result)
{
  // Something fetched a row from $result before this statement is run
  while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $data['realname'];
  }
}
```

Seeing how you're comparing two similar codes, you may have accidentally written something in between the two:

```
if($result)
{
  mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $data['realname'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Both records do not appear to be :(, yes maybe there is a command mysql_fetch_assoc ($result) before.

Answer (score 0):

> $result = mysql_query($query = "SELECT realname FROM t_user");
>
> if($result) {   while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
>       echo $data["realname"];   } }

```
$result = mysql_query($query = "SELECT realname FROM t_user");
 var_dump($data);die;
```

see the result array in your browser. the above while loop should work. check your result.

Comment: var_dump($data) result: bool(false)

Comment: try like below
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 var_dump($data);die;